# Why Collections.copy operation works on size of list instead of capacity of list?

Tags: java, collections

Below is the code, which I tried:

```
//Initialized the first list with initial capacity 2
List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>(2);
list1.add("banana");
list1.add("apple");

//Initialized the second list with initial capacity 4
List<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>(4);

//Performing copying
Collections.copy(list2, list1);
```

But copying operation failed with IndexOutOfBoundsOperation.
Reason :- source does not fit in dest.

> Question why copy operation is working on size i.e. no of elements in
>   a list?    Why it doesn't operate on capacity?

Comment: The capacity only makes sense for `ArrayList`s. The `Collections::copy` method needs to work with all types of collections. Having slightly different semantics depending on the type of collection would therefore be really confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)):

## copy

> Copies all of the elements from one list into another. After the operation, the index of each copied element in the destination list will be identical to its index in the source list. The destination list must be at least as long as the source list. If it is longer, the remaining elements in the destination list are unaffected.
> This method runs in linear time.

## throws

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the destination list is too small to contain the entire source List.
> UnsupportedOperationException - if the destination list's list-iterator does not support the set operation.

So well... it's just the desired behavior. In case you want to add all elements of one list to another, you can `List#addAll`.

Comment: My question is why It is like this?

Comment: @AmitBhati it's useful for achieving another list which has the same elements in the same order

Comment: But then you should fill the other list with the same no of elements i.e. in my case, I have to put two random values in list2, to achieve the copy of list1.

Comment: @AmitBhati - Q: Why does a bicycle have two wheels.  A: Because if it didn't have two wheels it would be a unicycle, or a tricycle, or ... a pogo stick.  To answer your question - it is designed this way because it is intended to fill a particular need.  If it was intended to fill a different need it would have been designed differently.

Comment: @Stephen well said, understood.

Comment: @AmitBhati I added the possible usage of this method to the answer

Comment: Why they (the designers) chose to fill this particular need and not a different one with this `copy` method is best answered by the designers themselves.  But frankly, *that* is one of those questions where the answer is moot; i.e. it changes nothing if you know the (real) answer or you don't.

Comment: @xenteros Your code snippet will cause the exact same exception that the OP's code causes (unless the `asc` `List` remains empty).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

This method is supposed to work for any two `List` implementations.

What if you run it with :

```
List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("1","2");
Collections.copy(l1,l2);
```

`Collections.copy` can't use `add` to increase the size of `l2`, since `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed size `List` and doesn't support `add`. Therefore the size of `l2` must be large enough to fit all the elements of `l1`.

Therefore, looking at the implementation, you'll see that `Collections.copy` uses `set` and not `add`.